# Give link hover same effect as href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to make hovering over a navigation anchor link act similarly to a href action, where hovering the link for an 'About' link (like in my site below) displays goes directly to the 'About' section of the page, and then moving the mouse away from the link goes back to the original div if the 'About' link is not clicked on?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZdzmB.

HTML:

```
<nav>

    <ul id="menu">

        <li>

            <a>Menu</a>

             <div id="dropdown">

            <ul>

                <li class="navLink active"><a href="#homeSection"><div class="navLine"></div>Home</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#aboutSection"><div class="navLine"></div>About</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#skillsSection"><div class="navLine"></div>Skills</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#workSection"><div class="navLine"></div>Work</a></li>

                <li class="navLink"><a href="#contactSection"><div class="navLine"></div>Contact</a></li>

            </ul>

            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

    </nav>

    <main>

        <section id="homeSection" class="section" data-anchor="home">

            <div class="sectionContent">

                <h1 id="intro">Intro text</h1>

            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="aboutSection" class="section" data-anchor="about">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="skillsSection" class="section" data-anchor="skills">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="workSection" class="section" data-anchor="work">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

        <section id="contactSection" class="section" data-anchor="contact">

            <div class="sectionContent">



            </div>

        </section>

    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use jQuery

```
$('.navLink').hover(function(){  
    $(this).trigger('click');  
});
```

Comment: Awesome username.

Comment: I don't know what this is meant to be doing, it has absolutely no effect whatsoever

Comment: you asked to have the hover perform the href action (which is click). This binds the hover of any navLink to perform a click on that navLink

Comment: It's not performing the href action

Comment: what do you mean by href action? where is that defined?

Comment: For each 'navLink'

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the .mouseover() function.

I updated your CodePen with these change: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxJWVp

Here's the Jquery Mouseover function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#1').mouseover(); 
});

$('#1').mouseover(function() {
$('#intro').html('Intro');

});

$('#2').mouseover(function() {
$('#intro').html('About Content goes here');

});

$('#3').mouseover(function() {
 $('#intro').html('Skills Content goes here');

 });

 $('#4').mouseover(function() {
 $('#intro').html('Work Content goes here');

 });

 $('#5').mouseover(function() {
   $('#intro').html('Contact Content goes here');

 });
```

Then just add the respective ' id = "1" '

```
<li class="navLink active" id="1"><a href="#homeSection">
<div class="navLine"></div>Home</a></li>
```